# Sway of Binary Tree

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-tree

[Original Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd51K.png)

The problem is as stated and my solution is below: Return the amount a BST tree sways in one direction.
Sway is denoted by the amount of nodes that are
"unbalanced" - nullptr on only one side, a left
swaying tree returns the negative amount it sways
with any right sway offsetting the left and vice versa

```
int tree_sway(Node * node){
   if(!node){
      return 0;
   }

   int m = tree_sway(node->right) + 1;
   int n =  tree_sway(node->left) - 1;

   return m - n;
}
```

For the tree sway problem, is the solution I have posted correct? If not, would the only way to do this problem be to create a helper function that keeps track of how many left and right turns the recursive step makes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have posted is not quite correct. For example, on a tree with a root and a leaf, the result will always be 0 regardless of which side the leaf is on. One way of doing it this:

```
int tree_swap(Node *node) {
    # base case of the recursion
    if (!node) { return 0; }

    # go down the left and right branches and add their scores
    int score = tree_swap(node->left) + tree_swap(node->right);

    # adjust the score for the missing children of the current node
    if (!node->left) { score++; }
    if (!node->right) { score--; }
    return score;
}
```

The general idea is that as you recurse, you first go all the way down the tree and as you come back up you count the missing left and right branches and pass the running tally up the tree.